# convert vb.net linq to c# linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have the following function in VB.net and am trying to convert it to C#, but I have having difficulty.  Could someone please help me out?

Here is the code:

```
    Dim subset = Sheets.Where(Function(kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Sheet)) kvp.Value.Members.Where(Function(m As Member) m.MemberType = MemberType).Count() > 0)
    subset.ToList().ForEach(Sub(kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Sheet)) WeightByType += (kvp.Value.Members.Sum(Function(m As Member) Convert.ToDecimal(m.TotalWeight, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))))
```

Comment: What have you come up with in C# so far? BTW using an actual `foreach` loop is [generally preferred](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) to using `ForEach()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
var subset = Sheets.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Members.Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberType).Count()> 0);
subset.ToList().ForEach(kvp => WeightByType += (kvp.Value.Members.Sum(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m.TotalWeight, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))));
```

Comment: Works up to the point that WeightByType is the name of my function. "public static decimal WeightByType(string MemberType)"

Answer (score 0):

That can all be simplified to the following

```
return Sheets
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Members.Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberType).Count() > 0)
    .Sum(kvp => kvp.Value.Members.Sum(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m.TotalWeight, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

Comment: Works up to the point that WeightByType is the name of my function "public static decimal WeightByType(string MemberType)"

Comment: If `WeightByType` is a method how are you using `+=` on it?  Is that some weird VB thing I'm not familiar with.

Comment: decimal wbt=0;
wbt += Sheets
        .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Members.Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberType).Count() > 0)
        .Sum(kvp => kvp.Value.Members.Sum(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m.TotalWeight, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
return wbt;

Answer (score 0):

I took both of the answers and used them. The new code looks like this:

```
decimal wbt = 0;
        wbt += MbrSheets
         .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Members.Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberType).Count() > 0)
         .Sum(kvp => kvp.Value.Members.Sum(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m.TotalWeight, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
        return wbt;
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you know about this, but there is a pretty good online code converter that Telerik has had up and running for a long time now.

I've had pretty good luck with it in the past. It will convert from VB to C# and vice versa.

http://converter.telerik.com

Comment: You should try it first with the OP's code... (interesting result).

Comment: It was a general statement Dave, no need to down vote as it is still a decent resource for conversions. Lambda's do seem to give it fits though.

Comment: I'm sure it's a decent resource - but I find it irritating when people recommend a resource which fails miserably on the question being asked.